# 3D aggregation of RasterBrick or RasterStack

Tags: r, aggregate, resampling, rescale

I have some data in a 3D grid identified by simple i,j,k locations (no real-world spatial information). These data are in a RasterStack right now.

```
b <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
# add more layers
b <- stack(b,b)
# dimensions
dim(b)
[1]  77 101   6
```

yields 77 rows, 101 columns, **6 layers.**

```
# upscale by 2
up <- aggregate(b,fact=2)
dim(up)
[1] 39 51  6
```

yields 39 rows, 51 columns, **6 layers.**

Hoped-for behavior: 3 layers.

I'm looking for a method to aggregate across layers in addition to the present behavior, which is to aggregate within each layer. I'm open to other data structures, but would prefer an existing upscaling/resampling/aggregation algorithm to one I write myself.

Potentially related are http://quantitative-advice.gg.mq.edu.au/t/fast-way-to-grid-and-sum-coordinates/110/5 or the [spacetime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spacetime/) package, which assumes the layers are temporal rather than spatial, adding more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the documentation correctly. To [aggregate across layers](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/aggregate):

> For example, `fact=2` will result in a new Raster* object with 2*2=4 times fewer cells. If two numbers are supplied, e.g., `fact=c(2,3)`, the first will be used for aggregating in the horizontal direction, and the second for aggregating in the vertical direction, and the returned object will have 2*3=6 times fewer cells. Likewise, `fact=c(2,3,4)` aggregates cells in groups of 2 (rows) by 3 (columns) and 4 (layers).

It may be necessary to play with `expand=TRUE` vs `expand=FALSE` to get it to work, but this seems inconsistent (I have [reported it](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6507&group_id=294&atid=1189) as a bug).

Answer (score 0):

Supouse you define `agg.fact` variable to denote the value 2:

```
agg.fact  <- 2
up <- aggregate(b, fact = agg.fact)
dim(up)
[1] 39 51  6
```

Now we generate a table which indicates which layers will be aggregate with anothers using `agg.fact`:

```
positions <- matrix(1:nlayers(b), nrow = nlayers(b)/agg.fact, byrow = TRUE)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
```

And apply a function(in this case `mean` but could be ``` max``, ```sum` or another ...) to each pair of layers

```
up2 <- stack(apply(positions, 1, function(x){
  mean(b[[x[1]]], b[[x[2]]])
}))

dim(up2)
[1]  77 101   3
```

Or if want to aggregate in 3 dimensions (choose if want aggregate 1-2d and then 3d or viceverza):

```
up3 <- stack(apply(positions, 1, function(x){
  aggregate(mean(b[[x[1]]], b[[x[2]]]), fact = agg.fact) #first 3d
  #mean(aggregate(b[[x[1]]], fact = agg.fact), aggregate(b[[x[2]]]), fact = agg.fact) ##first 1d-2d
}))
dim(up3)
[1] 39 51  3
```